# Does the sample mean of the fatter tailed distribution $\to +\infty$ faster if both diverge?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, \dots)$ and $Y = (Y_1, Y_2, \dots)$ be independent sequences of non-negative random variables such that
$$
X_i \overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} F \quad \text{and} \quad Y_i \overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} G,
$$
where $F$ and $G$ are cumulative distribution functions.

Also, let $E[X_1] = E[Y_1] = \infty$ and
$$
F(x) < G(x) \quad \text{for large $x$,}
$$
i.e. the $X_i$ have a fatter tailed distribution that the $Y_i$.

Does it then hold that
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbf 1 \big\{ \overline X_n \geq \overline Y_n \big\} = 1 \quad \text{almost surely,}
$$
where $\overline X_n = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $\overline Y_n = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\;$?

If not, does at least
$$
P(\overline X_n \geq \overline Y_n) \to 1
$$
hold?

**Thoughts**

It's well known that both sample means diverge almost surely to $+\infty$. But, intuitively, a fatter tail ought to make $\overline X_n$ diverge faster as $n \to \infty$.

But I'm not sure how to tackle the problem. I've tried using convolutions, but haven't gotten anywhere with that. I did a quick search for inequalities with Riemann-Stietjes integrals, since $E X_1 = \int_{\mathbb R} x \, dF(x)$, but didn't find anything.